Magento variable plugin is not defined magento 2
when we click on insert variable button that time magentovariableplugin is not defined got this error so we added adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml and issue is resolved but system configuration layout has been changed why ? 

Now, create adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml for update editor handle :
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
</page>

if it is not working.. then use:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Backend::js/bootstrap/editor.js"/>
    </head>
</page>

